# How to make sure all inserted instruction compiled?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization, riscv

I'm working on RISC-v ISA editing and there should be a compiler for my modified ISA.
The modification is to insert authentication code into return address and authenticate it. Thus, the new instruction should appear in pair when the program call and return from functions.
But when I'm using GNU toolchain for RISC-v, some authentication instructions disappeared in the binary, and that lead to fetch segfault because unauthenticated RA is out of range.

Here are the added parts of compiler: (pac and aut are instructions I added)

```
void
riscv_expand_prologue (int style)
{

...
//veriable defination and initialization

if (cfun-\>machine-\>naked_p)
{
gcc_assert (style == NORMAL_RETURN);

      emit_jump_insn (gen_return ());
    
      return;
    }

+ //load key
+ insn = emit(gen_lui(gen_rtx_REG(Pmode,T3_REGNUM),
+ GEN_INT(32)));
+ insn = emit(gen_slli(gen_rtx_REG(Pmode,T3_REGNUM),
+ gen_rtx_REG(Pmode,T3_REGNUM),
+ GEN_INT(32)));
+ //inserting pac into ra
+ insn = emit(gen_pac(gen_rtx_REG(Pmode,RETURN_ADDR_REGNUM),
+                      gen_rtx_REG(Pmode,RETURN_ADDR_REGNUM),
+                      gen_rtx_REG(Pmode,T3_REGNUM)));
+ add_reg_note (insn, REG_CFA_TOGGLE_RA_MANGLE, const0_rtx);
+ RTX_FRAME_RELATED_P (insn) = 1;

...

}

void
riscv_expand_epilogue (int style)
{

...
//veriable defination and initialization

if (cfun-\>machine-\>naked_p)
{
gcc_assert (style == NORMAL_RETURN);

      emit_jump_insn (gen_return ());
    
      return;

}

+ /\* pac \*/
+ //load key
+ insn = emit(gen_lui(gen_rtx_REG(Pmode,T3_REGNUM),
+ GEN_INT(32)));
+ insn = emit(gen_slli(gen_rtx_REG(Pmode,T3_REGNUM),
+ gen_rtx_REG(Pmode,T3_REGNUM),
+ GEN_INT(32)));
+ //authenticate ra and strip pac from ra
+ insn = emit(gen_aut(gen_rtx_REG(Pmode,RETURN_ADDR_REGNUM),
+                      gen_rtx_REG(Pmode,RETURN_ADDR_REGNUM),
+                      gen_rtx_REG(Pmode,T3_REGNUM)));
+ add_reg_note (insn, REG_CFA_TOGGLE_RA_MANGLE, const0_rtx);
+ RTX_FRAME_RELATED_P (insn) = 1;

...

}
```

when I compiling helloworld c program, I found the number of aut instruction is only half of pac's. But I searched the source code of RISC-v gcc and found the `riscv_expand_prologue` function and `riscv_expand_epilogue` function are called in pair.

What should I do to make these two instructions properly appeared in pair in the prologue and epilogue?